# Not able to install scapy module in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, module

I am using python version 2.7 and Pycharm IDE , I installed scapy module via pycharm UI (file --- default setting -- added scapy)

```
from scapy.all import DNS


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from arch import *
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from bsd import *
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scapy/arch/bsd.py", line 12, in <module>
    from unix import *
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pcapdnet import *
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 173, in <module>
    import dnet
ImportError: No module named dnet
```

when I run above statement it shows above error , I installed scapy module successfully ...

Comment: Is that full code ? where is the `dnet` comes from ?

Comment: No , This error I got when I run in python terminal

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `libdnet`

```
$ wget http://libdnet.googlecode.com/files/libdnet-1.12.tgz
$ tar xfz libdnet-1.12.tgz
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd python
$ python2.5 setup.py install
```

For 64 bit....

```
$ CFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure
$ archargs='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' make
```